# Получить уникальные ID с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть **ID** вида *AA111*, но некоторые из них повторяются.

Нужно получить только уникальные **ID** с помощью регулярного выражения.

Сейчас я использую

```
Regexp = r'[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}',
```

но получаю все **ID**. Не имею большого опыта с регулярными выражениями, поэтому прошу помощи.

Comment: Собирайте получаемые `ID` в **множество**, тогда они у вас будут без повторений. А чисто с помощью регулярок, кажется, нельзя только уникальные значения получить.

Comment: @CrazyElf Ну почему невозможно. Negative-lookahead, и будут вам только уникальные. Пример: `re.findall(r"([A-Z]{2}\d{3})(?!.*\1)", "AA123,CD876,XX000,AA876,ZQ111,AA123,GG555")`